# Count amount of same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple task which I to be honest have no idea how to accomplish. I have these values from SQL query:

```
| DocumentNumber | CustomerID |
------------------------------
|  AAA           |     1      |
|  BBB           |     1      |
|  CCC           |     2      |
|  DDD           |     3      |
-------------------------------
```

I would like to display a bit modified table like this:

```
| DocumentNumber | CustomerID |  Repeate |
-----------------------------------------
|  AAA           |     1      | Multiple |
|  BBB           |     1      | Multiple |
|  CCC           |     2      | Single   |
|  DDD           |     3      | Single   |
------------------------------------------
```

So, the idea is simple - I need to append a new column and set 'Multiple' and 'Single' value
depending on if customer Id exists multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by CustomerId) = 1 then 'Single'
             else 'Multiple'
        end) as repeate
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You also achieve the Same By using **GROUP BY & SUB QUERY**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
DocumentNumber VARCHAR(10),
CustomerID INT)

Insert Into @T VALUES('AAA', 1 ),('BBB', 1 ),('CCC', 2 ),('DDD', 3 )

select M.DocumentNumber,M.CustomerID,CASE WHEN Repeated_Row>1 THEN 'Multiple' ELSE 'Single' END As Repeate 
from @T M
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CustomerID,COUNT(*) AS Repeated_Row FROM @T GROUP BY CustomerID) S ON S.CustomerID=M.CustomerID
```